# Breaker Identification

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, replacement

I am looking to replace a breaker in my panel; however, it looks like many of the breakers are from manufacturers that no longer offer products. I have a Bryant panel with many Bryant breakers installed, but it appears that some of these breakers have been replaced over the years. I've added a picture of the specific breaker I need to replace.

The label indicates it's a type A tandem 15 amp breaker with no common trip. The issue number is LP-3113, but I haven't been able to determine a manufacturer that uses issue numbers like this. It resembles modern Siemens breakers, but I am not confident in that identification. I would appreciate any help in identifying an appropriate replacement.

[image: Breaker - Close-up1]

Comment: Please [edit] to provide clear pictures of the panel label (which may be on the door, or may be inside the panel) and while we are at it might as well get a nice detailed one of all the breakers, from which the sparkies will be able to tell you which ones don't belong and should be replaced (and what with, using the information from the label and who makes **listed** replacements for what.) This one is a bit out of focus on the fine print where it matters, for that matter.

Comment: So I am guessing this is a non current limiting Tandem, or one that dose not have the limiting feature, a photo of the back will help to figure out what you have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Back in the day, Challenger made a panel design.  The bus assembly was excellent, but they cheated the UL listing on their breakers. They don't trip when they're supposed to.  They were type C for normal breakers and type A for tandems.  Challenger folded up business and sold their designs to BRyant. BRyant threw the Challenger breaker design in the dumpster, and kept the bus assembly design and renamed it BR.

They changed the name specifically to **ban**  the faulty type A/C breakers.  But since the bus design was actually the same, BR fit Challenger, and BR breakers are *cross-listed* type A or C.  Good for Challenger owners.  Doesn't do anything for you.

Your panel is listed for Type BR breakers, and Type C or A are not allowed here, because they cheated their UL listing.

Into the trash it goes.

You should be using BR breakers exclusively. I don't recommend tandems, but if you must use them, it'll be a BR1515 or BD1515, now sold by Eaton. (the difference is CTL, but consult Eaton for whether those rules still apply).

I concur that it might have been private-labeled by ITE or somebody for Challenger. A lot of smaller makers did not make their own tandems. Note the Type C/A bus clip and LED speed lettering, not normally seen on Siemens.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected an Eaton replacement would work, and after reading your response. I purchase a BR1515 without CTL. Just finished installing it and everything is working fine.